# Need help writing Linux script to automate moving files when flash drive is inserted

Tags: linux, script, automation, sd-card, raspbian

I am trying to use a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian to automatically move (not copy) the contents of Folder A (local) to Folder B (on SD card via USB to SD card reader) automatically when the card/adapter is inserted. I also want it to increment the name of Folder B by 1 or the date or something, so it is easy to tell batches apart. The script should run at boot, and send the shutdown command after the file transfer has finished. Note: there will be no screen attached to the Pi when this is all done. Thanks in advance!